# Solve $|3-x|=x-3$.

Tags: absolute-value

> Solve: $|3 - x| = x - 3$.
>
> Answer: $|u| = -u$ when and only when $u \le 0$. So, $|3 - x| = x - 3$ when and only when $3 - x \le 0$; that is, $3 \le x$.

Hi! I'm new here. I'm working out of this book called Schaum's Outlines 3,000 Solved Problems in Calculus. I understand that when solving for absolute values that you have to draw two equations, for example when solving for $|x+3|<5$ you must solve for both $x+3<5$ AND $x+3>-5$. But can someone please explain the process above to me? I don't understand it. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to understand *why* you need to solve two things, or *what* you need to solve, or *how* to solve it? (or something else?)

Comment: Yes what exactly are you wondering? it seems as if you posted the worked solution

Comment: @BenMillwood I think the OP is confused because there is only one case that needs to be considered. He or she has been solving equations using absolute values by separating them into cases, and here that is not what is happening.

Comment: Do you understand the piecewise definition of the |x|?

Comment: That is $|x|=x$ if $x \ge 0$ or $|x|=-x$ if $x<0$

Comment: I'm confused as to how the posted solution works. But the answer by GFauxPas makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

This is the definition of the absolute value of a real number that we are using:

$$|x| = \begin{cases}x; & x > 0 \\ 0; & x = 0 \\ -x; & x < 0\end{cases}$$

The equation to be considered is:

$$|3 - x| = x - 3 = \begin{cases}3 - x; & 3 - x > 0 \\ 0; & 3 - x = 0 \\ -(3 - x); & 3 - x < 0\end{cases}$$

We see that we don't need to consider $ 3 - x > 0$ because that case doesn't make sense. Only $3 - x = 0$ and $3 - x < 0$ will give you sensible answers. Conclude $ 3 \le x$.

Comment: (+1) Almost exactly what I was going to write, but your answer turned up before I finished.

Comment: Why don't we need to consider 3-x>0? Why doesn't that case make sense?

Comment: @chris.the.saint Suppose $3 - x > 0$ so $x \ne 3$. You have $3 - x = x - 3$ implying $x = 3$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: I believe your third case is wrong because the absolute value of a number can only be positive or 0.

Answer (score 0):

$|-u|=|-1 \cdot u|=|-1| \cdot |u|=1 \cdot |u|=|u| \\ |u|=u \text{ if } u \ge0 \\ |3-x|=|(-1)(x-3)|=|x-3| \\ |x-3|=x-3 \text{ if } x-3 \ge 0$

Answer (score -1):

the graph of $y = |3-x|$ is $v$-shaped with the vertex at $(3,0)$ and it lies in the upper half plane. on the left of $x = 3$ is the line $y = 3 - x$ and to the right is  the line $y = x - 3$  the equation $|3-x| = x - 3$ is satisfied for all $x \ge 3.$